# RuntimeError RoR...Called id for nil, which would mistakenly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

On my merchants index page I am trying to show the amount of credit that the current logged-in user has with each particular merchant. Note that on the list there might be merchants where the user has no credit.

RuntimeError in Merchants#index

Showing .../app/views/merchants/index.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

```
<ul class="list-group">     
    <% @merchants.each do |merchant| %>
      <a href="/merchants/<%= merchant.id %>" class="list-group-item "><%= merchant.name %>   
        <% if Credit.where(:user_id => @current_user.id, :merchant_id => merchant.id).count > 0 %>
   line9->  <%= Credit.where(:user_id => @current_user.id, :merchant_id => merchant.id).sum(:amount) %>
        <% end %> 
      </a>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error implies either `@current_user` or `merchant` is nil. @Richard Peck's advice below is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put pure SQL in your views - that's what controllers are for

You should do this:

```
#app/models/credit.rb
class Credit < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :active, -> { where("amount IS NOT NULL") }
end

#app/controllers/credits_controller.rb
def index
    @credits = current_user.credits.active #-> only shows active credits
end

#app/views/credits/index.html.erb
<ul class="list-group">     
<% @merchants.each do |merchant| %>
  <a href="/merchants/<%= merchant.id %>" class="list-group-item "><%= merchant.name %>   
    <%= @credits.sum(:amount) if @credits.present? %>
  </a>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, I think I get your point about not putting pure SQL on the views. But the thing is that if I use the code just as you suggested, I get for each Merchant list-group-item the Total Amount of credits that the user has in the system. And I need to iterate over each merchant to show on each Merchant list-group-item the Total Amount of credit that the user has with that particular Merchant. Am I clear?